# Когда использую pip pyinstaller вылезает ошибка SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Я так понял что у меня не правильный код

```
    # Калькулятор

from colorama import init
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style

# use Colorama to make Termcolor work on Windows too
init()

print( Fore.BLACK )
print( Back.GREEN )

what = input( "Что делаем? (+, -)" )

print( Back.RED )

a = float( input("Введи первое число: ") )
b = float( input("Введи второе число: ") )

print( Back.CYAN )

if what == "+":
    c = a + b
    print("Результат: " + str(с))
if what == "-":
    c = a - b
print("Результат: " + str(с))
else:
    print("Выбрана неверная операция!")

imput()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вероятнее всего ошибка здесь

```
if what == "+":
    c = a + b
    print("Результат: " + str(с))
if what == "-":
    c = a - b
print("Результат: " + str(с))
else:
    print("Выбрана неверная операция!")
```

перед вторым `print` надо поставить отступ

```
if what == "+":
    c = a + b
    print("Результат: " + str(с))
if what == "-":
    c = a - b
    print("Результат: " + str(с))
else:
    print("Выбрана неверная операция!")
```

а также у вас в конце опечатка

```
imput()
```

замените на

```
input()
```